# Latest Chromium >= 78.0.3904.87 - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Snap or Apt or something else?

Tags: 16.04, apt, chromium, snap, vulnerability

There are are a couple of [critical vulnerabilities CVE-2019-13720 and CVE-2019-13721 for Chrome/chromium](https://www.cisecurity.org/advisory/multiple-vulnerabilities-in-google-chrome-could-allow-for-arbitrary-code-execution_2019-118/) which require an update to version 78.0.3904.87 or greater.

I'm running Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed via apt - and the latest available version is only 77.0.3865

```
ツ apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 77.0.3865.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 77.0.3865.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 77.0.3865.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

I could uninstall this and use snap, which has a newer version:

```
ツ snap info chromium
name:      chromium
summary:   Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
publisher: Canonical✓
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   Apache-2.0 AND BSD-3-Clause AND LGPL-2.0 AND LGPL-2.1 AND MIT AND MS-PL AND (GPL-2.0+ OR LGPL-2.1+ OR MPL-1.1)
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all
  Internet users to experience the web.
snap-id: XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
channels:
  stable:    78.0.3904.70 2019-10-29 (920) 160MB -
  candidate: 78.0.3904.70 2019-10-29 (920) 160MB -
  beta:      79.0.3945.16 2019-11-04 (925) 155MB -
  edge:      80.0.3955.4  2019-11-04 (927) 155MB -
```

Which is newer - but even that is not quite the stated version with the fix (.70 instead of the required .87 patch/build number).

So - is there a way to get a patched version of Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04? Installing Chrome isn't really an option (tinfoil hat issues) upgrading to 18.04 probably is - but I fear I'd need a free weekend to do it safely.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something.... but the version from snap edge, is super close to latest chromium build? https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+refs Only around 1 week behind from what I can see.

Comment: Yup, _super_ close, only a couple of days before the CVE was published. But without someone confirming, I have to assume it doesn't include the fix :(

Comment: "which require an update to version 78.0.3904.87 or greater". 78.0.3904.87 < 80.0.3955.4. `snap install --channel=edge chromium`

Comment: Boom! You're a genius and I'm an idiot - I can install beta or edge using snap. Want to make that an answer for upvotes, accepts and general respect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install using snap, and set to beta or edge:

`snap install --channel=edge chromium`